# Problem reading variable column headings with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, indexing

I have a python script that extracts data from a csv file for processing.  The the data I am working with looks something like this

```
Time.     Col1.     Col2.     Col3.     Important
 0.1       .02       .03       .02      .02
 0.2.      .03       .03       .02      .03
```

The script extracts the Time and Important columns for processing.  When all columns are present, the script works fine using

```
# specify the row headers seven lines down the file
    names = ['Time (s)', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Important']
    df = pd.read_csv(fle,
                     delim_whitespace=True,
                     error_bad_lines=False,
                     encoding='utf-8',
                     names=names,
                     skiprows=7)
```

My issue is that when producing the file, a user can reject certain columns, meaning I may up with a column less.

```
Time.     Col1.    Col3.     Important
 0.1       .02       .03       .02
 0.2.      .03       .03       .03
```

But because my 'names' list has all the headings that could be in the file, the script doesn't recognise the column headings and doesn't process these files.  (it doesn't produce an error, just the resulting plots are blank as though there is no data).

This script iterates through a folder of 50 or so files, which have anywhere between 3 to 9 columns but two of those are always Time and Important.

Is there a way to tell pandas that some or all of the column headings in the 'names' list may be present?

I have tried just shortening the 'names' to only 'Time' and 'Important' but this generates an error later in the code when I have to index specific positions of Time column.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...inter-through-filesv2.py", line 55, in <module>
    loop_start = df[df['Time (s)'] == start].index.item()
  File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 719, in item
    return self.values.item()
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell pandas that not all of the column headings in
>   the 'names' list may be present?

You can simply omit the `names` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fle, delim_whitespace=True, error_bad_lines=False,
                 encoding='utf-8', skiprows=7)
```

Then assign column names in a subsequent step:

```
n = len(df.columns)
df.columns = ['Time (s)'] + [f'Col{i}' for i in range(1, n-1)] + ['Important']
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work (I think I may not have explained the question well).  The script iterates over a folder of 50 or so of these files.  Some files have all of the columns, some have a column or two missing.  But in all cases I only want Time and Important columns to be identified.  I have edited the question to be clearer.  When I try your suggestion, I get a length mismatch error when the script encounters a file with all the columns since there are 3 identified in the script but the file actually has 4.

Comment: @nick.sculthorpe, See update. You can create a list of columns dependent on how many columns you find in your dataframe.

Comment: That worked great and marked as the answer.  Thank you!  (also I think the f at the start of the second [ ] is a typo?)